# NSFetchedResultsController problem

Tags: iphone

When I try to set up a cell in a UITableViewController that has a NSFetchedResultsController I am getting an error as soon as I try to get to the managedObject. The error is:

```
2009-12-08 16:21:47.610 Take10[4837:20b] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0xa08dd140 of class 'List' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2009-12-08 16:21:47.610 Take10[4837:20b] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0xa08dd140 of class 'List' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

Here is my code, crash comes when trying to set up the managed object:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Get the managedObject
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"listName"];

return cell;
}
```

I've looked at the class code for the managedBobject that is retrieved by the fetch, and it looks fine, an automatically generated class from my Core Data model. If I use another entity from the model in the same fetch, all works perfectly.

Ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem: the class name List is invalid. I changed it to CheckList and all is well.

Jk

Comment: Be aware, same error for subclasses of NSManagedObject named "Object"!

Answer (score 2):

I'd always used the actual Entity class that was retrieved -- looks like "List" in your case -- rather than calling it an `NSManagedObject` (`List *list = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]`). I wouldn't suspect that just from the error message, but it's the only thing that looked off to me.

Edit:
This is unlikely to be the problem, but it's my last guess -- you're sure you imported "List.h"? Otherwise it could think it's just 'id'. The methods its complaining about are implemented in NSObject, so I can't imagine that they aren't there.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but the error is the same. It knows the managed object is of type List, but thinks there is a problem with the class for some reason.

Comment: @Alpinista I think this guy deserves at least an up-vote from you because he was pretty close to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does your model class inherit from NSObject? This error usually happens when this is not the case.

Comment: When you create your class from the model editor it should inherit from NSManagedObject by default.

Comment: Yep, the class is of type NSManagedObject. The two other entities in the model work fine. Might I have caused a problem when pre-populating the table in the SQLLite dB??